# Divide 2 Bigints (Find percentage change)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bigint, bignum

I have 2 numbers:

```
 const a = 61921447244562694144000n;
 const b = 93068664972055293198336n;
```

and I'm trying to find a percentage change between them.

So far I tried 3 methods - using just numbers, using BigInts and JSBI.

```
const percentageChange = ((a - b ) / b) * 100n);
```

This method is not working because this calculation with BigInts will always give just once digit due the limitations with decimals - BigInt always rounds up the number.

With just numbers I got the answer, but it was incorrect (guess because of the large numbers)

JSBI giving many different errors, but I still can't wrap my head arround it:

```
 let a = JSBI.subtract(oldValue, newValue);

     
 let b = JSBI.divide(a, oldValue);
```

jsbi errors such as:

```
TypeError: _.__digit is not a function
```

or

```
Error: Convert JSBI instances to native numbers using `toNumber`.
```

Comment: JSBI is not expected to work with real BigInts. It's designed to be a polyfill for environments where you don't have built-in `BigInt` support. You can't mix the two. Also, JSBI is never a way to work around limitations of native BigInts, because it's meant to behave the same way. If you use pure JSBI operations (such as `var a = JSBI.BigInt("6192"); var b = JSBI.BigInt("9306"); JSBI.multiply(JSBI.divide(JSBI.subtract(a, b), b), JSBI.BigInt("100"))`, then the result is guaranteed to be the same as with native BigInts.

Comment: Just convert them to floating point numbers? Or do you have any specific accuracy requirements?

Comment: @jmrk I didn't know that. Thank you for clarifing.

Comment: @Bergi I think JS is not very good with such large floating point numbers

Comment: @AdamS. What do you mean by "*is not very good*"? Even if not precisely representing the integers, floating point numbers seem totally fine for computing the ratio. In your example they amount to `-0.33466922230854856`. Again, what are your accuracy requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the order of operations:

```js
const a = 61921447244562694144000n;
const b = 93068664972055293198336n;

const percentageChange = (a - b ) * 100n / b;

console.log(percentageChange.toString());
console.log(Number(percentageChange));
```

You can add even more digits:

```js
const a = 61921447244562694144000n;
const b = 93068664972055293198336n;

const percentageChange = (a - b ) * 1000n / b;

console.log(Number(percentageChange) / 10);
```